Truffle test error "VM exception" ERC721
I have just created a .sol contract inheriting from openzeppelin ERC721. I have also written some tests, but I get the following errors:

Here is the code for .sol file:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.4.24;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";

contract StarNotary is ERC721 {

    constructor(string memory name_, string memory symbol_) ERC721 (name_, symbol_) {}

    struct Star {
        string name;
    }

    mapping(uint256 => Star) public tokenIdToStarInfo;
    mapping(uint256 => uint256) public starsForSale;

    
    // Create Star using the Struct
    function createStar(string memory _name, uint256 _tokenId) public { // Passing the name and tokenId as a parameters
        Star memory newStar = Star(_name); // Star is an struct so we are creating a new Star
        tokenIdToStarInfo[_tokenId] = newStar; // Creating in memory the Star -> tokenId mapping
        _mint(msg.sender, _tokenId); // _mint assign the the star with _tokenId to the sender address (ownership)
    }

    // Putting an Star for sale (Adding the star tokenid into the mapping starsForSale, first verify that the sender is the owner)
    function putStarUpForSale(uint256 _tokenId, uint256 _price) public {
        require(ownerOf(_tokenId) == msg.sender, "You can't sale the Star you don't owned");
        starsForSale[_tokenId] = _price;
    }


    // Function that allows you to convert an address into a payable address
    function _make_payable(address x) internal pure returns (address payable) {
        return payable(x);
    }

    function buyStar(uint256 _tokenId) public  payable {
        require(starsForSale[_tokenId] > 0, "The Star should be up for sale");
        uint256 starCost = starsForSale[_tokenId];
        address ownerAddress = ownerOf(_tokenId);
        require(msg.value > starCost, "You need to have enough Ether");
        transferFrom(ownerAddress, msg.sender, _tokenId); // We can't use _addTokenTo or_removeTokenFrom functions, now we have to use _transferFrom
        address payable ownerAddressPayable = _make_payable(ownerAddress); // We need to make this conversion to be able to use transfer() function to transfer ethers
        ownerAddressPayable.transfer(starCost);
        if(msg.value > starCost) {
            payable(msg.sender).transfer(msg.value - starCost);
        }
    }

}

And here for the tests:
const StarNotary = artifacts.require("StarNotary");

var accounts;
var owner;

contract('StarNotary', (accs) => {
    accounts = accs;
    owner = accounts[0];
});

it('can Create a Star', async() => {
    let tokenId = 1;
    let instance = await StarNotary.deployed();
    await instance.createStar('Awesome Star!', tokenId, {from: accounts[0]})
    assert.equal(await instance.tokenIdToStarInfo.call(tokenId), 'Awesome Star!')
});

it('lets user1 put up their star for sale', async() => {
    let instance = await StarNotary.deployed();
    let user1 = accounts[1];
    let starId = 2;
    let starPrice = web3.utils.toWei(".01", "ether");
    await instance.createStar('awesome star', starId, {from: user1});
    await instance.putStarUpForSale(starId, starPrice, {from: user1});
    assert.equal(await instance.starsForSale.call(starId), starPrice);
});

it('lets user1 get the funds after the sale', async() => {
    let instance = await StarNotary.deployed();
    let user1 = accounts[1];
    let user2 = accounts[2];
    let starId = 3;
    let starPrice = web3.utils.toWei(".01", "ether");
    let balance = web3.utils.toWei(".05", "ether");
    await instance.createStar('awesome star', starId, {from: user1});
    await instance.putStarUpForSale(starId, starPrice, {from: user1});
    let balanceOfUser1BeforeTransaction = await web3.eth.getBalance(user1);
    await instance.buyStar(starId, {from: user2, value: balance});
    let balanceOfUser1AfterTransaction = await web3.eth.getBalance(user1);
    let value1 = Number(balanceOfUser1BeforeTransaction) + Number(starPrice);
    let value2 = Number(balanceOfUser1AfterTransaction);
    assert.equal(value1, value2);
});

it('lets user2 buy a star, if it is put up for sale', async() => {
    let instance = await StarNotary.deployed();
    let user1 = accounts[1];
    let user2 = accounts[2];
    let starId = 4;
    let starPrice = web3.utils.toWei(".01", "ether");
    let balance = web3.utils.toWei(".05", "ether");
    await instance.createStar('awesome star', starId, {from: user1});
    await instance.putStarUpForSale(starId, starPrice, {from: user1});
    let balanceOfUser1BeforeTransaction = await web3.eth.getBalance(user2);
    await instance.buyStar(starId, {from: user2, value: balance});
    assert.equal(await instance.ownerOf.call(starId), user2);
});

it('lets user2 buy a star and decreases its balance in ether', async() => {
    let instance = await StarNotary.deployed();
    let user1 = accounts[1];
    let user2 = accounts[2];
    let starId = 5;
    let starPrice = web3.utils.toWei(".01", "ether");
    let balance = web3.utils.toWei(".05", "ether");
    await instance.createStar('awesome star', starId, {from: user1});
    await instance.putStarUpForSale(starId, starPrice, {from: user1});
    let balanceOfUser1BeforeTransaction = await web3.eth.getBalance(user2);
    const balanceOfUser2BeforeTransaction = await web3.eth.getBalance(user2);
    await instance.buyStar(starId, {from: user2, value: balance, gasPrice:0});
    const balanceAfterUser2BuysStar = await web3.eth.getBalance(user2);
    let value = Number(balanceOfUser2BeforeTransaction) - Number(balanceAfterUser2BuysStar);
    assert.equal(value, starPrice);
  });


You're facing the custom error of ERC721 due to insufficient approval (i.e., ERC721InsufficientApproval error), because the owner of the underlying token needs to approve the transfer of token (for a particular token id) to the receiver, and then only the transferFrom function can be executed successfully.
With you current logic of the StarNotary contract, you explicitly need to call the approve function from the owner's account, before calling the buyStar function. So, your revised tests would be:
it('lets user1 get the funds after the sale', async () => {
    let instance = await StarNotary.deployed();
    let user1 = accounts[1];
    let user2 = accounts[2];
    let starId = 3;
    let starPrice = web3.utils.toWei(".01", "ether");
    let balance = web3.utils.toWei(".05", "ether");
    await instance.createStar('awesome star', starId, { from: user1 });
    await instance.putStarUpForSale(starId, starPrice, { from: user1 });
    let balanceOfUser1BeforeTransaction = await web3.eth.getBalance(user1);

    // Approving the token to user2
    await instance.approve(user2, starId, { from: user1 });

    await instance.buyStar(starId, { from: user2, value: balance });
    let balanceOfUser1AfterTransaction = await web3.eth.getBalance(user1);
    let value1 = Number(balanceOfUser1BeforeTransaction) + Number(starPrice);
    let value2 = Number(balanceOfUser1AfterTransaction);
    assert.equal(value1, value2);
});

it('lets user2 buy a star, if it is put up for sale', async () => {
    let instance = await StarNotary.deployed();
    let user1 = accounts[1];
    let user2 = accounts[2];
    let starId = 4;
    let starPrice = web3.utils.toWei(".01", "ether");
    let balance = web3.utils.toWei(".05", "ether");
    await instance.createStar('awesome star', starId, { from: user1 });
    await instance.putStarUpForSale(starId, starPrice, { from: user1 });
    let balanceOfUser1BeforeTransaction = await web3.eth.getBalance(user2);

    // Approving the token to user2
    await instance.approve(user2, starId, { from: user1 });

    await instance.buyStar(starId, { from: user2, value: balance });
    assert.equal(await instance.ownerOf.call(starId), user2);
});

it('lets user2 buy a star and decreases its balance in ether', async () => {
    let instance = await StarNotary.deployed();
    let user1 = accounts[1];
    let user2 = accounts[2];
    let starId = 5;
    let starPrice = web3.utils.toWei(".01", "ether");
    let balance = web3.utils.toWei(".05", "ether");
    await instance.createStar('awesome star', starId, { from: user1 });
    await instance.putStarUpForSale(starId, starPrice, { from: user1 });
    let balanceOfUser1BeforeTransaction = await web3.eth.getBalance(user2);
    const balanceOfUser2BeforeTransaction = await web3.eth.getBalance(user2);

    // Approving the token to user2
    await instance.approve(user2, starId, { from: user1 });

    await instance.buyStar(starId, { from: user2, value: balance, gasPrice: 0 });
    const balanceAfterUser2BuysStar = await web3.eth.getBalance(user2);
    let value = Number(balanceOfUser2BeforeTransaction) - Number(balanceAfterUser2BuysStar);
    assert.equal(value, starPrice);
});


NOTE: If you want to automate this approval, then you can revise your StarNotary contract in such a way  that it transfers the token to the contract when the token is put for sale (i.e., when putStarUpForSale is called). And, you can store the addresses of the original owners inside the tokenIdToStarInfo mapping, by adding the owner field to the Star struct.  Then, in the buyStar function, the approval can be done from within the contract (because the contract is holding the token) using this.approve(msg.sender, _tokenId).
Here's the revised contract code by doing the above mentioned changes:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.4.24;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";

contract StarNotary is ERC721 {

    constructor(string memory name_, string memory symbol_) ERC721 (name_, symbol_) {}

    struct Star {
        string name;
        address owner;
    }

    mapping(uint256 => Star) public tokenIdToStarInfo;
    mapping(uint256 => uint256) public starsForSale;

    
    // Create Star using the Struct
    function createStar(string memory _name, uint256 _tokenId) public { // Passing the name and tokenId as a parameters
        Star memory newStar = Star(_name, msg.sender); // Star is an struct so we are creating a new Star
        tokenIdToStarInfo[_tokenId] = newStar; // Creating in memory the Star -> tokenId mapping
        _mint(msg.sender, _tokenId); // _mint assign the the star with _tokenId to the sender address (ownership)
    }

    // Putting an Star for sale (Adding the star tokenid into the mapping starsForSale, first verify that the sender is the owner)
    function putStarUpForSale(uint256 _tokenId, uint256 _price) public {
        require(tokenIdToStarInfo[_tokenId].owner == msg.sender, "You can't sale the Star you don't owned");
        transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _tokenId);
        starsForSale[_tokenId] = _price;
    }


    // Function that allows you to convert an address into a payable address
    function _make_payable(address x) internal pure returns (address payable) {
        return payable(x);
    }

    function buyStar(uint256 _tokenId) public payable {
        require(starsForSale[_tokenId] > 0, "The Star should be up for sale");
        uint256 starCost = starsForSale[_tokenId];
        address ownerAddress = tokenIdToStarInfo[_tokenId].owner;
        require(msg.value > starCost, "You need to have enough Ether");
        starsForSale[_tokenId] = 0;
        this.approve(msg.sender, _tokenId);
        transferFrom(address(this), msg.sender, _tokenId); // We can't use _addTokenTo or_removeTokenFrom functions, now we have to use _transferFrom
        address payable ownerAddressPayable = _make_payable(ownerAddress); // We need to make this conversion to be able to use transfer() function to transfer ethers
        ownerAddressPayable.transfer(starCost);
        if(msg.value > starCost) {
            payable(msg.sender).transfer(msg.value - starCost);
        }
    }

}

With this contract, your original tests would work fine as you don't need to explicitly call the approve function from the owner (i.e., user1) account.
